# File input stream in java - calculating data

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

I am trying to read in a file into the program and then take fileIn objects and do calculations on them to create a new variable, specifically take a read in price and calulate sales tax. I have done this type of program before and I did it the way my code is below. For some reason this time I am getting this error message in the console when I run the program.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at TaxCalculator.main(TaxCalculator.java:42)
```

What I have found so far is that the .next() method is giving me errors, becaus I am able to read in a full line with .nextLine();, however this defeats the purpose of the program.

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class TaxCalculator {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner fileIn = null; //Initializes fileIn to empty

    //Declares variables
    String text;
    int value;
    double price;
    double tax;

    try 
    {
        //Attempt to open the file
        fileIn = new Scanner (
                new FileInputStream ("Basket.txt"));

        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        //This block executed if the file is not found
        //then the program exits
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }



    //Read and print in lines
    value = fileIn.nextInt();
    text = fileIn.next();
    price = fileIn.nextDouble();
    tax = (price * .10);

    System.out.printf("%1d %2s %3.2f", value, text, price   );


    /**
    //Read and print next input line
    value = fileIn.nextInt();
    text = fileIn.next();
    price = fileIn.nextDouble();
    tax = (price * .10);    
    System.out.printf("%-7s %20s %22s %30.2f %n", value , text, text,
            price);
    //Read and print next input line
    value = fileIn.nextInt();
    text = fileIn.next();
    price = fileIn.nextDouble();
    tax = (price * .10);    
    System.out.printf("%-7s %18s %22s %30.2f %n", value , text, text,
            price);
    **/
    // Close file
    fileIn.close();

    System.out.println("\nEnd of Tax Calculator");


  }

 }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
    -Edit - 
       content of Basket.txt

```
1 item at 10.49
1 special item at 13.99
1 candy bar at 0.75

Input 2:
1 imported pack of cigarettes at 10.00
1 imported bottle of alcohol at 44.50

Input 3:

1 imported bottle of alcohol at at 25.99
1 bottle of alcohol at 15.99
1 packet of cough drops at 4.99
1 box of imported cigarettes at 9.25
```

Comment: can you post `Basket.txt` content?

Comment: Added content of Basket.txt to post

Answer (score 1):

Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

It means that your program has tried to read a value that is an integer that is not an integer.

Comment: `Scanner#next` returns a `String`, maybe there was no more input to read.

Comment: The stack trace provides that it was a nextDouble() method call.

Comment: It was something along these lines. I think the format specifier was actually mismatched with one of the scanner values.

Answer (score 0):

The `Basket.txt` contains strings with integer ,

`value = fileIn.nextInt();
    text = fileIn.next();
  price = fileIn.nextDouble();`

reads first three lines , so the first three lines should be in **Integer**  **String**  **double** if it is string or mixed string , it will show

```
MismatchException
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first three lines be `int`, `String` and `double` if that's the case?

Comment: Yea the program will not skip lines to read in a double which comes after a string.

Comment: If we want to read the code that contain all `string` `Integer` `double` means we can go with `try{value = fileIn.nextInt();
    text = fileIn.next();
    price = fileIn.nextDouble();}catch{}` option